# Powershell Script to add switch's interfaces into arrays

Tags: powershell, switching

Firstly, I'm not super proficient in powershell to begin with.

I'm looking for a way to create arrays with a cisco switch's interfaces in each.
More specifically, the way I'm writing it currently, I need a way to add a `$line.StartsWith()` into an array, then end it with another `$line.StartsWith()`, along with all lines in between the two of those.  Preferably, also create a new array for each interface.

Currently, for this part of my script, I've got

```
foreach($line in $config) {
    if($line.StartsWith('interface Gig') -or ($line.StartsWith('interface TenGig'))) {$interface = @($line)}
```

This was just to test if it was working so far and it is.. So I need to end each array with `$line.StartsWith('!')`, then begin a different array with `$line.StartsWith('interface Gig')` -or `($line.StartsWith('interface TenGig')`

Is there a fairly simple way to do this?  Maybe I'm not using the correct wordage, but I'm not finding it via the Googles.

Comment: What about using a RegEx `foreach($line in $config) { if($line -match '^interface (Ten)?Gig'){...}` the `?` makes the capture group `(Ten)` optional.

Comment: Also show more of your input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

$interface =@{}

foreach($line in $config) {
    if($line.StartsWith('interface Gig') -or ($line.StartsWith('interface TenGig'))) {$interface += @($line)}

Comment: $interface | select-object @{n="interface"; e={$interface[$_]}} | export-csv -path yourpath -notypeinformation